# Partitions: reading skew diagrams?

Tags: notation, integer-partitions

Consider the following two partitions. Partition $\lambda=4^4=(4,4,4,4)$

```
o o o o 
o o o o
o o o o
o o o o
```

And partition $\mu=(4,2,1,0)$

```
o o o o 
o o 
o
```

We can take the skew diagram of the two partitions $\lambda-\mu$ (or in other notation $\lambda /\mu$)

```
. . . .
. . o o
. o o o
o o o o
```

Now the question is, how do we read the resulting skew diagram in terms of partitions? Do we write

$$\lambda-\mu =(0,2,3,4)?$$

This does not seem right, since the elements of all partitions usually are ordered in decreasing order. Additionally, using such an object within a formula for construction of symmetric polynomials would lead to vanishing results if the partition is not ordered (see for example [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0112035v4.pdf) paper). So the question remains: how exactly does one read a skew diagram as a partition?
Thanks for any suggestion!

EDIT:

In the notation section of [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0112035v4.pdf) paper the interpretation

$$(m^n-\mu)_i=m-\mu_{n+1-i}$$

is given, so that I guess in the above example we have $\lambda-\mu =(4,3,2,0)$. But that still does not tell us what to do when both $\lambda$ and $\mu$ have non-trivial shapes and i.e. $\lambda/\mu$ is a vertical strip.

Answer (score 1):

A skew diagram is not a partition, so you cannot write it as a tuple.  I would just write "$\lambda/\mu$ where $\lambda = 4444$ and $\mu = 421$."  You need to keep both $\lambda$ and $\mu$ around to describe $\lambda/\mu$.  Of course, if you're interested in some special situation you could make up your own notation.

Comment: The problem is that explicit examples of symmetric polynomials are supposed to be constructed by setting explicit partitions and performing summations over the entries. That means, $\lambda/\mu$ should be a sequence of integers, to make sense in the summation.

Comment: There's no obvious way to write an arbitrary skew shape as a sequence of integers.  I wouldn't get bogged down in coming up with a notation - if you can't find anything in the literature, just invent your own or just describe what you mean in words.